# PTIJ: What's the difference between Arur Mordechai and Baruch Haman?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

What's the difference between Arur Mordechai and Baruch Haman? *Is* there a difference?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Not *strictly* a duplicate, as the other inexplicably asks about Moshe not Mordechai, but I assume that was part of the other poster's confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gematriah of Arur Haman and Baruch Mordechai is the same. However the gematriah of Arur Mordechai and Baruch Haman are not the same. Thus, even when drunk you can no longer mix them up.